# How do the massive gauge bosons eat up the would-be Goldstone bosons?

Tags: gauge-theory, higgs

In the literature one often reads that the would-be Goldstone bosons of the spontaneously broken $SU(2)\times U(1)$ symmetry are *eaten up* by the longitudinal polarisation vectors of the now massive gauge bosons. While I find this explanation pictorially nice, I want to see the maths behind it.

My idea is that the other DOFs of the Higgs $SU(2)$ doublet, let us call them $w,z,\zeta$, will become part of the $W^\pm$ amd $Z$ fields after reparametrisation. Is that true?

The literature usually writes out $(D_\mu\langle\Phi\rangle_0)^\dagger D^\mu\langle\Phi\rangle_0$ first and then reparametrises the fields as
$$W^\pm_\mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(W^1_\mu\pm iW^2_\mu\right), Z_\mu=\cos\theta_WW^3_\mu-\sin\theta_W B_\mu.$$

Is it that one has to write out the full covariant derivate square of the full Higgs doublet? I mean this:
$$D^\dagger_\mu\begin{pmatrix}w-iz\\ v+H-i\zeta\end{pmatrix}^T D^\mu\begin{pmatrix}w+iz\\ v+H+i\zeta\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Your text should detail precisely that. Are you asking for a textbook recommendation? [Kibble's summary](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Englert-Brout-Higgs-Guralnik-Hagen-Kibble_mechanism#Spontaneous_breaking_of_a_local_gauge_symmetry) details it for the Abelian case, and you generalize for the nonabelian case by your last term, keeping just the covariant completions, not the actual derivatives in the covariant derivatives!

Comment: @CosmasZachos Now I do not anymore think that my idea with the square of the covariant derivative of the full Higgs doublet is true. It will only give the interaction terms with the unphysical Higgs components. But I will check out Kibble's summary as soon as I have the time. It looks promising.